# Pass html source into a bash script and manipulate it

Tags: html, bash, stdin

I apologize if a question like this has been answered already, but I'm too new to bash scripting to tell if it has been answered or not.

I'd like to pass the html source of a web page to the script so that it can modify/scrape the web page of its HTML tags. An example of the things I've tried:

> cat webpage.htm | ./dosomething

The code for dosomething would be as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

export LC_ALL='C'

echo "testing"
echo $1 #this is the part where I'd like to be able to access the html that I've passed into the script
echo "still testing"
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' < $1 #trying to strip the html tags of the webpage that I've passed in
```

When cat didn't work, I tried:

> ./dosomething < webpage.htm

My script code didn't work for that either. The script needs to read HTML from standard input and modify it before putting the modified HTML to standard output - I can't pass the web page in as an actual argument like this:

> ./dosomething webpage.htm

Comment: please do a google search for 'parse html in bash'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to strip html tags from the webpage, this has already been solved by the command line browsers. have a look at the lynx -dump option

```
lynx -dump http://www.subir.com/lynx.html
```

elinks has a similar option, not too sure about w3c

Answer (score 0):

Since the source is already fed to the script via standard input, commands within the script inherit this input, so you must not redirect the input there - drop the `< $1`.

Now good luck for your courageous undertaking of processing HTML in bash.